# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at end of input

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to put a query in a python script but get error:

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...LOAT*(db_lo+db_hi) ) ) END) AS Lx_pop                FROM R2

My query is as follow:

```
sql=    "DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW IF EXISTS "+schema1+"."+vue_out+";\
            CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "+schema1+"."+vue_out+" AS\
            WITH\
            -- Select Population Table and transform MultiPolygons into Polygons (ST_Dump)\
            P0 AS (\
            SELECT\
                gid\
               ,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS geom\
               --,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom::geometry(Polygon,31370) AS geom\
               ,ST_NumGeometries(the_geom) AS Ngeom\
               ,pop_2014 AS tot_pop\
               ,ST_area(the_geom) AS tot_Area\
            FROM\
                "+schema2+"."+table_in_2+"\
            ORDER BY ST_NumGeometries(the_geom) DESC\
            ),\
            -- Compute Area and distribution population over Split multipolygons:\
            P AS (\
            SELECT\
                P0.*\
               ,ST_area(geom) AS area\
               ,tot_pop*ST_area(geom)/tot_area AS pop\
            FROM P0\
            ),\
            -- Select and filter out (2016) Power Profile and transform MultiPolygons into Polygons (ST_Dump)\
            N AS (\
            SELECT\
                gid\
               ,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS geom\
               --,(ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom::geometry(Polygon,31370) AS geom\
               ,year\
               ,db_lo\
               ,db_hi\
               ,ST_area(the_geom) AS Area\
            FROM\
                "+schema1+"."+table_in_1+"\
            WHERE\
                year = 2016\
            ),\
            -- Compute Intersection after joining only overlapping polygons\
            R0 AS (\
            SELECT\
               P.gid AS pgid\
              ,P.pop AS tot_pop\
              ,P.area AS tot_area\
              ,N.gid AS ngid\
              ,N.year\
              ,N.db_lo\
              ,N.db_hi\
              ,(ST_Dump(ST_intersection(P.geom, N.geom))).geom AS geom\
            FROM\
               P JOIN N ON ST_intersects(N.geom, P.geom)\
            ),\
            --  Compute area of intersections:\
            R1 AS (\
            SELECT\
                row_number()over() AS gid\
               ,pgid\
               ,ngid\
               ,year\
               ,tot_pop\
               ,tot_area\
               ,db_lo\
               ,db_hi\
               ,geom::geometry(Polygon, 31370) AS geom\
               ,ST_area(geom) AS area\
            FROM\
               R0\
            ),\
            -- Distribution population over polygons: \
            R2 AS (\
            SELECT\
                R1.*\
               ,area/tot_area*tot_pop AS Pop \
            FROM R1\
            )\
            -- Final Aggregates:\
            SELECT\
                R2.* \
                ,(CASE WHEN Pop = 0 THEN '-infinity'::FLOAT ELSE 10::FLOAT*log( pop*10::FLOAT^( 0.05::FLOAT*(db_lo+db_hi) ) ) END) AS Lx_pop\
            FROM R2"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case, it was resolved by removing the commented-out lines. (The ones with `--` in them.)